# How can I get Perk Points?

Tags: payday-2

[Update 39](http://steamcommunity.com/games/218620/announcements/detail/221000653215151241) added perk decks that require **perk points** to unlock. But I don't know how to acquire these points, as it's not explained in the update log and I kind of skipped past the tutorial prompt.

[image: PERK DECKS]

How do I get perk points to spend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get perk points based on the amount of experience you gain. Currently, every **100-1000 EXP** (depending on your level) gets you **1 perk point**. This is done automatically, and you will see a nice little information prompt when go see your perk decks:

[image: EXP TO PERK CONVERSION. CONVERSION RATE: 1000:1]

Comment: 1000:1 ratio is when your level is >= 90 (friend was level 86, was getting 900:1 ratio). I'm quite sure the ratio is 100:1 for < 10, 200:1 < 20 etc